# Estimate $f$ from $\widehat{f}$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Given $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\widehat{f} \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, let's define for $\lambda > 0$ the function
$$\psi_\lambda(t) =  \sum_{-\infty}^\infty f \left(\frac{t-2\pi n}{\lambda}\right)$$
then clearly $\psi_\lambda$ is $2\pi$-periodic and belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ where $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R}/2\pi \mathbb{Z}$. The question is, the author Katznelson in "Introduction to Harmonic Analysis" claim that (page 149)

"$\widehat{f} \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$" implies that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\lambda>0$ small enough so that
$$ \sup_{t\in \mathbb{T}} |\psi_\lambda(t)| < \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)| + \varepsilon$$
Can I anyone explain it to me rigorously?

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it, but comments are welcome.

Since $\widehat{f}\in \mathcal{S}(\widehat{\mathbb{R}})$ we have $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ as well, thus 
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} (2\pi + |x|)^2 |f(x)| \leq C  \qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad |f(x)| \leq \frac{C}{(2\pi+|x|)^2} \quad\text{for all}\quad x\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation*}
For $t\in \mathbb{T}\sim [0,2\pi)$ and $n\neq 0$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\left|f\left(\frac{t-2\pi n}{\lambda}\right)\right| \leq \frac{C\lambda^2}{\big(2\pi + |t-2\pi n|\big)^2} \leq \frac{C\lambda^2}{\big(2\pi + 2\pi |n| - t\big)^2} \leq \frac{C\lambda^2}{4\pi^2 |n|^2}.
\end{equation*}
Hence
\begin{equation*}
|\psi_\lambda(t)| \leq \left|f\left(\frac{t}{\lambda}\right)\right| + \sum_{n\neq 0} \left|f\left(\frac{t-2\pi n}{\lambda}\right)\right| \leq \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)| + \frac{C\lambda^2}{4\pi^2} \sum_{n\neq 0}\frac{1}{n^2} = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)| + \frac{C\lambda^2}{24}
\end{equation*}
and thus the result follows when we choose $\lambda$ small enough.